# Google maps display a gray background when its renderer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to implement a simple google maps using swift.
The map should be displayed in a `UIView`.

Well, I follow the next steps:
I added a `UIView` element in my storyboard with the class `GMSMapView`

And declared in my `ViewController` with:

`@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 51.050657, longitude: 10.649514, zoom: 5.5)
            let map = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
            self.mapView = map


        }
```

And `GMSServices.provideAPIKey("xxx-xxx")` in my `AppDelegate.swift`.

Ok, those codes aren't returning any error, but in my screen it's displayed the Google text in colors and a gray background without the map.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It should be the key or GMSMap permission problem. Check your key and allow permission to the GMSMap in your Google Account.

Comment: @emresancaktar you right! for some reason, was disabled. Thanks for the help

Comment: happy coding m8

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This issue occur when the **Google Maps SDK** is not enable for your API Key .
For enabling it , open your developer console at https://console.developers.google.com . On the left handside select library.
Select **Google Map SDK for iOS** under **Google Maps Api** heading and click enable for enabling the **Google Map SDK** . That's it , you will now have your same old beautiful maps.

Comment: Just chiming in that my API Key is enabled and I'm still having this problem, so something else must also be causing this

Comment: @GregHilston Same here.

Comment: @MakwanBarzan Apologies, I don't recall what fixed my situation, as its been some time and I no longer do iOS development. Good luck!

Comment: @GregHilston Never mind, we hopefully could resolve that by re-generating a new API key. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

This issue may also occur if your API Key is not properly configured in AppDelegate.m in IOS and AndroidManifest.XML in Android

AppDelegate.m

> GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"XXXXYOUR-API-KEYXXX"]; // check
> "*YOUR_API_KEY*" underscore is removed.